# Windows 7 -Can't get access to shared folder from one computer to another

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

I have 2 windows 7 computers and i'm trying to share a folder (that I want password protection on) outside of the homegroup.

Both computers are part of the same workgroup and I have the same user account/password combination on both computers plus I have password protected sharing turned on in the network and sharing centre along with file and printer sharing turned on.

On computer 1 I have right clicked and selected that I want the folder shared.  When I navigate via the network on computer 2 to computer 1 the shared folder shows up on computer 2 but double clicking on it to open it gives me an alert saying I don't have permission to access it, no option to type in the user name and password (according to the help files I shouldn't even need to type the password in if both computers have the same username/password anyway but would need it if I'm logged in as a different user).  It's just a blanket denial of access.

Answer (score 1):

Try mapping it as a [network drive](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3673.html) and providing a different user name in step 6. If that doesn't work try the [Net Use](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html) command to change the credentials used when accessing the machine. Windows will only allow you to connect to a machine using one set of credentials, so sometimes it trys to connect to say a printer first with the guest account, and that is why you can't access the shared folder using different credentials. "net use * /delete" will clear any existing connections.

Also I have had strange problems before where I was only able to use the Administrator account to connect, but that was probably because I was using [hidden administrative shares](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314984)